# how to detect the projector status for mac

Tags: ios

I need to moniter the changes in the screen whether it is connected to projector or not. I tried nsactivity but it is showing nil while printing the type.

Answer (score 1):

For **Mac** App:
`NSScreen` Class object describes the attributes of a computer’s monitor or screen. You can get all screen by:

```
let screens = NSScreen.screens
```

You could implement [applicationDidChangeScreenParameters(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate) in your app delegate (the method is part of the NSApplicationDelegateProtocol)

For **iOS** App:
`UIScreen` Class object defines the properties associated with a hardware-based display. for getting all connected display can use:

```
let screens = UIScreen.screens
```

To monitor connect/disconnect of external display in **iOS** you can register a notification observer on:

```
UIScreenDidConnectNotification
UIScreenDidDisconnectNotification
```

These notification is posted when a new screen is connected/disconnected to the iOS device.

Comment: can you tell me screen sharing is running or not in mac

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187426/can-i-know-how-to-detect-the-screen-sharing-is-running-or-not-in-mac